# quickfixengine: possible to restrict logging?

Tags: quickfix

In [**quickfixengine**](http://www.quickfixengine.org/) is there a setting to specify the log level to restrict number of messages logged? It seems that we are login a lot of data so we would like to restrict it  bit. I assume that logging too many messages should affect performance (don't have any hard data for or against).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't say which language you're using but I believe that this should work with both the C++ and Java APIs.

You will need to implement your own [LogFactory](http://quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/class_f_i_x_1_1_log_factory.html) and [Log](http://quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/class_f_i_x_1_1_log.html) classes (the former is responsible for creating instances of the latter).  Then you'll pass an instance of your custom `LogFactory` to your `Initiator` or `Acceptor` instance.  Your `Log` class is where you will do the message filtering.

Understand that [Log](http://quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/class_f_i_x_1_1_log.html) receives messages in string form, so you'll need to filtering either with string matching operations or convert the strings back to [Messages](http://quickfixengine.org/quickfix/doc/html/class_f_i_x_1_1_message.html) and then filter using tags, though this may end up slowing you down more than just allowing all messages to be logger.